# rompre, casser, briser, fracasser, et crever

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, synonymes

Contrairement à ma langue maternelle, le français regorge de mots pour signifier « rompre ». J’ai besoin de votre aide pour découvrir comment les emplois de ces mots diffèrent.
Mes impressions ci-dessous sont-elles correctes ?

J’ai vu les mots *rompre, casser, briser, fracasser*, et *crever* utilisés dans des livres que j’ai lu. Selon mon dictionnaire, et mes propres pensées:

- **Rompre** exprime « séparer un seul objet en deux morceaux »,
- **Casser** veut dire « séparer un seul objet en plusieurs morceaux »,
- **Briser** est utilisé pour « casser quelque chose en très beaucoup d’éclats » et est lié à *broyer*,
- **Fracasser** est un peu comme *briser* mais avec encore plus de vigueur et, en dernier lieu,
- **Crever** égale à peu près *déchirer*.

Cette suite contient sans doute des fautes. Je serais ravi de recevoir des réponses qui me montrent le vrai rapport entre ces mots et m’apprennent comment je dois les utiliser.

Comment: Voir aussi: http://www.cnrtl.fr/proxemie/casser

Comment: `crever` signifie faire un trou, alors que `déchirer` signifie couper en (au moins) deux parties distinctes de façon moins propre que si c'était découpé.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dépendant de la situation, la plupart de ces mots sont interchangeables, pas étonnant qu'on s'y perde! Cette réponse est rédigée au Québec et ne fait que donner un point de vue québécois sur la question - je suis francophone, pas linguiste! ;)

Votre définition de *rompre* me semble adéquate, sinon que *rompre* et *casser* peuvent également être utilisés pour "mettre fin à une relation amoureuse", *casser* faisant généralement allusion à la fin d'une amourette, alors qu'une *rupture* (ou une *séparation*) fait plus sérieux.

On *crève* un ballon ou un pneu (on dit alors qu'il a une *crevaison* ou, au Québec, "un *flat*" [prononcer "flatt"]), ou comme @Circeus a mentionné, tout ce qui se gonfle. On *crève* un ballon avec une épingle, mais si on le gonfle trop, il *éclate* comme une bulle. Idem pour le pneu.

On *fracasse* une fenêtre ou une vitrine, on *défonce* une porte ou même un mur.

On *brise* généralement un mécanisme; on peut aussi se *briser* ou se *fracturer* un os en ski, mais on dira qu'on s'est *cassé* une jambe ou un bras.

On *déchire* du papier, mais les sportifs vous diront qu'on peut aussi *se déchirer* un ligament avec un mouvement mal exécuté et/ou un réchauffement inadéquat.

Answer (score 2):

*Crever* s'emploie pour des choses qui enflent et/ou gonflent comme des bulles de savon et des ballon. Ou emploie aussi *éclater* dans ce sens.

Answer (score 2):

Aux deux réponses précédentes j'ajouterai l'utilisation de *rompre* pour le pain. « Rompre le pain », expression d'origine religieuse (Nouveau Testament) qui dans le vocabulaire courant, et par extension, signifie partager un repas de façon conviviale et amicale.
On peut aussi signaler la différence entre *rompre le pain*, c'est à dire le casser avec les mains (ce que les français peuvent facilement faire avec une baguette) et le *trancher*, ce qui nécessite un couteau.

Answer (score 2):

*Crever* c'est faire un trou de part en part de quelque chose d'a priori relativement mince.  C'est beaucoup plus proche de *percer* (*crever* est plus violent) ou *fendre* (qui implique une ouverture plus ou moins linéaire) que de *déchirer* qui part du bord.

Answer (score 2):

**Casser** signifie aussi mettre hors service, sans nécessairement obtenir plusieurs morceaux: *ma voiture est cassée*.

On peut aussi ajouter le familier **péter** à la liste.

Comment: Péter (familier) est un synonyme de casser, mais prend plus le sens de "rendre inutilisable" que de "séparer en plusieurs morceaux" même si c'est un des moyens pour y parvenir.

Comment: @mansuetus - J'ai un avis différent. Péter est aussi synonyme d'exploser, qui a bien pour effet de séparer en plusieurs morceaux.

Comment: va pour ajouter la définition d'exploser à péter (je pense aux bombes et aux ampoules)

Answer (score 2):

"Rompre" peut signifier aussi mettre fin à quelque chose dans le temps. Comme un serment, une relation amoureuse, un engagement.